# SQL query to alter table column names

Tags: php, mysql

I am running this SQL Query in PHP:

```
$sql="alter table callplandata change '".$_POST["col_name$y"]."' '".$_POST["col_newname$y"]."' ";
```

to alter column names but before it updates i want to check if the column name already exists and if it does to add a number on the end otherwise to just carry on updating

how can i do this using PHP?

Comment: is that same query are you using in production server ? you might want to look at prepared statements

Comment: And you also might escape the user input to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: i know about SQL Injections and its fine. i will be changing to PDO once i have this sorted

Comment: Why wait? It just causes more work with development...it may be better to get started with this now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' 
AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name'
```

In PHP

```
$result = mysqli_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `table` LIKE 'fieldname'");
$exists = (mysqli_num_rows($result))?TRUE:FALSE;
```

Comment: Please, remove the code using `mysql_*` extension. It's deprecated, unsafe and not actively maintained. It's going to be removed in the future, don't rely on it. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead

Comment: OK Elias Van. Replaced mysql with mysqli

Comment: You didn't: you posted invalid code! RTFM: `mysqli_query` expects 2 arguments

Answer (score 2):

Please, please, please, don't do this. This is about as unsafe a thing to do. However, I will say this: The [`ALTER TABLE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) is worth a look:

```
ALTER TABLE <table name>
    CHANGE [COLUMN] old_col_name new_col_name column_definition
```

Note that the *column_definition* bit is *not* optional.
Also, if you want to see if the fieldname given already exists:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM <table_name> /* or SHOW COLUMNS IN tbl */
```

Then, in PHP, depending on the extension you used, you do something like this:

```
$existingFields = array();
foreach ($resultSet as $row)
{
    $existingFields[] = $row['Field'];
}
```

`SHOW COLUMNS` will also give you information concerning the type of each field, if it's a key, or even if it's an auto_increment value [details, as ever, on the mysql website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html)

So putting it all together:

```
$db = new PDO();//connect
$stmt = $db->prepare('SHOW COLUMNS IN callplandata WHERE Field = :field');
$bind = array(
    ':field'    => $_POST['colname_new']
);
$stmt->execute($bind);
if ($row = $stmt->fetch())
    throw new InvalidArgumentException($_POST['colname_new'].' already exists!');
$bind[':field'] = $_POST['colname_old'];
$stmt->closeCursor();//reset cursor, so we can re-use the statement
$stmt->execute($bind);//re-use statement
if (!($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    throw new InvalidArgumentException($_POST['colname_old'].' does not exist, cannot rename it!');
//very basic column definition construction here, needs more work, though!
$current = '';
$current = $row->Type. ' '.($row->Null == 'NO' ? 'NOT NULL ' : '').
    ($row->Default !== '' ? 'DEFAULT '.$row->Default.' ' : '').$row->Extra;
/**
 * ADD CODE HERE TO SANITIZE THE NEW COLUMN NAME
 * if you want to procede with this madness... I would urge you not to, though!
 */
$pdo->exec(
    'ALTER TABLE callplandata
         CHANGE '.$_POST['colname_old'].' '.$_POST['colname_new'].' './/rename
    $current//add column definition
);
```

Disclaimer:
The code I posted here is meant to be purely academic. It should not be used, it's unsafe and incomplete. Please rethink what you are trying to do. Avoid, at all cost, using *user data* to alter how the ***server*** stores/structures the data!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify datatype and default value also.
example

```
ALTER TABLE `ca_4_4_14`  CHANGE `active` `is_active` ENUM('Y','N') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT 'Y' NOT NULL;
```